# C#: Recursively get Dictonary value with deep string expression

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, recursion

I want to get an object from a `Dictionary<string, object>` using a string expression as key.
For example taking the following data structure:

```cs
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
  { "Products", new object[]
    {
      new Dictionary<string, object>()
      {
        { "Name", "Tin of biscuits"  }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to return the product name with the expression: `"Products[0].Name"`.
This is just an example, the data could be of any depth and the string expression could be something like `"BookStore.Books[3].Author.ContactDetails.Address"` for eg.

So far I have been experimenting with Recursive methods and have also tried `string.Split('.')` with [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) Linq method, but I am struggling and I think this is a perfect little puzzle for SO.

Comment: Ugh, what a horrendous data structure.. why not use something to hat already exists/with a query strategy like this, for example an xml document..?

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't mention but in the raw format the data is YAML, so this data structure is the same as the deserialised .NET structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'll always have the `Dictionary<string, object>` and `object[]` in your data structure, this approach should work:

```
private static object? GetSelectedValueOrDefault(this Dictionary<string, object> data, string selector)
{
    string[] selectorSegments = selector.Split('.');

    if (selectorSegments.Length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    object? currentNode = data.GetValueOrDefault(selectorSegments[0]);

    if (currentNode == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    for (int index = 1; index < selectorSegments.Length; index++)
    {
        string segment = selectorSegments[index];

        if (currentNode is not Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var selectorWithIndex = GetSelectorAndElementIndexOrDefault(segment);

        if (selectorWithIndex is not null &&
            currentNode is Dictionary<string, object> dict)
        {
            currentNode = dict.GetValueOrDefault(selectorWithIndex.Value.ItemSelector);
            currentNode = GetElementOrDefault(currentNode, selectorWithIndex.Value.Index);
            continue;
        }

        currentNode = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(segment);

        if (index == selectorSegments.Length - 1)
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static object? GetElementOrDefault(object? currentNode, int index)
{
    if (currentNode is not object[] array)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (index >= array.Length)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return array[index];
}

private static (string ItemSelector, int Index)? GetSelectorAndElementIndexOrDefault(string segment)
{
    if (!segment.Contains('['))
    {
        return null;
    }

    string[] result = segment.Split('[', ']');
    return (result[0], int.Parse(result[1]));
}
```

**Example**

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {
        "BookStore",
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {
                "Name",
                "The Book Store"
            },
            {
                "Books",
                new object[]
                {
                    new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                    new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                    new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                    new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {
                            "Author",
                            new Dictionary<string, object>()
                            {
                                {
                                    "Name",
                                    "Luke T O'Brien"
                                },
                                {
                                    "ContactDetails",
                                    new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                    {
                                        {
                                            "Address",
                                            "Some address"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(data.GetSelectedValueOrDefault("BookStore.Name"));
Console.WriteLine(data.GetSelectedValueOrDefault("BookStore.Books[3].Author.Name"));
Console.WriteLine(data.GetSelectedValueOrDefault("BookStore.Books[3].Author.ContactDetails.Address"));
```

**Output**

```
The Book Store
Luke T O'Brien
Some address
```

Comment: Thanks for using my name as the author, you get a +1 for that!